# MVC ActionResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a controller named `ToolsController`. This controller has an `ActionResult GetName` which returns a string ("Hello name"). I was able to hit the ActionResult like this  `localhost:52703/Tools/GetName?name=Ed`. Now suddenly stop working, and I don't see a reason why.

`localhost:52703/Tools/GetName?name=Ed`

```
    public ActionResult GetName(string name)
    {            
        return Content("Hello " + name);

    }
```

Note: I did not created a route for this, and I don't want to create one.

So the ActionResult is not getting hit anymore, and it was working for the past 3 weeks.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to provide more information.  What is the error you get?  "It doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: Well like I said, It is just a controller and there is no more code to it. When I tried to call the method from the browser nothing happen and then I get redirected to the Error.cshtml page even when  it should be giving me the YSOD (Yellow Screen) because I have my Web.config setup to do so <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" >. So, I'm not able to see any errors.

Comment: You can temporarily set `customErrors` to `Off`. What happens if you set a break point on the `return Content("Hello " + name);` then run in debug?

Comment: It is not stepping into the breakpoint. The weird thing, is that it was working before and there is not rocket science behind it. I should be able to call that ActionResult straight from the browser local:52703/Tools/GetName?name=Ed and get the result back. This is the way it works for my other projects. Instead of using routes for everything, I use http request with params and they work.

Comment: What happens when you set `customErrors` to `Off`? Is there an YSOD? You might also check the event log of the server which might contain more information about the exception.

Comment: Well, for some reason the request is being routed to a different controller Home>Index. But, it was no doing this before. When I construct the url this way localhost:52703/Tools/GetName?name=Ed it should be hitting Tools>GetName and not Home>Index.

Comment: What are your routes that have been setup?  I assume that the reason that it is not getting what you expect is because it is hitting the default route.  Looks like you are using the local IIS instance, has the port number changed?